# How can I specify the working directory while running R CMD check?

Tags: r, package

The command `R CMD check` runs the R files in the project's tests directory.

The directory structure:

```
toplevel
  project
    R
      rmongo.R
    tests
      RMongo-Ex.R
```

When I `R CMD check` project in toplevel directory, i run into this error:

```
cannot open file '../R/rmongo.R': No such file or directory
```

because my test file sources the R code file `source('../R/rmongo.R', chdir = TRUE)`

How can I make `R CMD check` cd into the test directory before running test file?

Comment: I'd recommend looking at an existing CRAN package with a similar layout (eg R/, tests/, ...). Run R CMD check and/or R CMD INSTALL on that, and if it works there then adapt your layout accordingly.  Works for 2500+ other packages :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The files in tests are test against the package after it's built so I just included library('name-of-package') in the test file and it was able to build.